# "Multivaluedness" of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x^n$

Tags: limits

So $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x^n=\begin{cases}
0, \ \ \ |x|<1 \\
\infty, \ \ \ x>1 \\
1, \ \  x=1 \\ 
[\text{I don't know}], \ \ \ x=-1 \\
\text{IDK}, \ \ x<-1 
                                 \end{cases}$$
Please elucidate on the last two limits, and also please tell what is the reason of this multivaluedness. 
**EDIT**: Wolfram speaks! 

[image] 
$=$[image]

[image] 
$=$[image] 
But I don't understand what does it mean. 
For $x=-2$, Wolfram gives complex infinity. Now please throw light on these things.

Comment: Your original question is most definitely a question on real analysis, so complex numbers are very off topic. Regardless, how did you get W|A to say Limit[...]?

Comment: Firstly, I don't know what is real-analysis. Secondly, by \lim_{n\to0} x^n.

Comment: For the assumptions part, put a comma (,) and write the condition.

Comment: Well, the fact that you are allowed to write $x>1$ means $x$ is real valued, so wolfram is not telling you what you want it to. It seems that what wolfram is doing is treating $n$ as a continuous variable, and telling you the 'asymptotic values' that $x^n$ can take. For $(-1)^n$, this is the unit circle. For $x^n$, where $x<-1$, there is a huge range of values for which I think it is only telling you that it does not become infinity at any finite choice of $x$ or $n$. The following page may be useful. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two limits don't exist. For $x=-1$, we see that the values oscillate between $-1$ and $1$ infinitely often, so there can't be a limit.

For $x<-1$, if $x^n → k < ∞ $ then $|x^n| = |x|^n → |k|$. But $|x|^n→∞$ by the second case. This plus the fact that $x^n$ consistently changes sign (just like the $x=-1 $ case) means that $x^n\not→ ± ∞ $ as well.

As for a 'reason for the multivaluedness', [have a look at the following plot of powers of $x$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%2Cx%5E2%2Cx%5E3%2Cx%5E4%2Cx%5E5)[image]
(source is Wolfram|Alpha)

---

regarding your edit, wolfram seems to think that $x$ could be complex valued. A sequence $z_n∈\Bbb C$ tends to complex infinity if $|z_n|→∞$ as a real-valued sequence. This should be something you ignore, given the context of the original question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers...also on meta.

Answer (score 0):

The limit doesn't exist for $x\le -1$. (For $x=-1$, you get the sequence: $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$ and for $x < -1$ you get something that is alternating in sign and increasing in size.)

There is no "multivaluedness" here. For each value of $x$, the limit is something (or fails to exist).

Taking a limit of non-constant functions, there is no reason to expect that the limit is constant (independent of $x$).

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha appears to interpret $x$ as a complex number. If that's what you want, you should say so. Your question didn't become any clearer after your edit.

Comment: Even if it does, then please can you show the method?