# Compute the Integral $\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{e}\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x\left(\ln x\right)^{7}\right)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$I=\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{e}\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x\left(\ln x\right)^{7}\right)}dx$$
Well my first thoughts after seeing this problem were substituting $x \to \frac{1}{x}$ and Feynman Integration Technique due to the $7$ as the power of $\ln(x)$.

The substitution leads to:
$$I=\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{e}\frac{x}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(x-\left(\ln x\right)^{7}\right)}dx$$
which according to me does not seem to be leading anywhere.

Differentiating under the Integral Sign by Introducing a parameter by replacing $7$ does not help either.

$$I(\alpha)=\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{e}\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x\left(\ln x\right)^{\alpha}\right)}dx$$

I did try to numerically integrate it and use Integer Relation Algorithms, but that did not give me any results.

Though from what I have numerically calculated
$$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}I(\alpha)=\frac{e}{\pi}$$
But don't take my word on it, as I am not sure about this result.

EDIT:

Thank you to @ClaudeLeibovici for showing that this result is incorrect. I think the closeness of the values ($\frac{e}{\pi}$) might just be a mere coincidence.

Also it seems as $\alpha \to \infty$, the whole graph falls within the lines $x=\frac{1}{e}$ and $x=e$ which are indeed the limits of integration.

$$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{e}\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x\left(\ln x\right)^{\alpha}\right)}dx \stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x\left(\ln x\right)^{\alpha}\right)}dx$$
[image]

EDIT:
I have found the original source for the Integral:

[Romanian Mathematical Magazine, Page 25](http://www.ssmrmh.ro/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/RMM-CALCULUS-MARATHON-2201-2300_compressed.pdf)

Here is an Image:
[image]
It seems the solution posted is wrong, in the third line of the solution, the $x^2$ term mysteriously disappears from the numerator.

**Apologies to everyone who worked on this problem, I do not have any reason to believe that the Integral might have a closed form.**

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment so I could improve the post?

Comment: It's probably nothing. It seems like a good enough post worth answering (if I even can). Is there a reason you think that integral can be evaluated?

Comment: @Accelerator Well the Integral is posted as a question somewhere, so I do believe it can be evaluated.

Comment: @Ercanayan No I think it's $x$ only. Please recheck.

Comment: Did you notice that the results align along two curves depending on the parity of $\alpha$ (when it is an integer) ? Concerning the mysterious downvote for a good question, welcome to the club of victims.

Comment: @BlackEmperor yes my bad, in search for symmetry i missed an extra $x^2$, WA returns 0.8380, (irrelevant- $arctanx=t$ looked very promising  but i am curious if $\int \frac{1}{1+tanx(ln(tanx))^7}\,dx$ has a closed form.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for pointing that out, I just graphed the functions and saw them. I have made an edit too.

Comment: @Ercanayan Could you resend the answer you got a while back, seems like the original answer of this question is the same as yours, but of course it does not match numerically.

Comment: These downvoters have nothing to do with math and have don't have the courage to explain why they downvoted ... this problem will continue as long as MSE lives.

Comment: Maybe the form $\frac12\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\text{sech}(x)}{e^xx^7+1}dx$ helps?

Comment: @TymaGaidash. Could you put an answer for this nice result ?

Comment: It is true that the proposed solution does [not match](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Nintegrate%5B1%2F%28%28x%5E2%2B1%29+%28x+ln%28x%29%5E7%2B1%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C1%2Fe%2Ce%7D%5D%2C%28e-1%29%2F%282+%28e%2B1%29%29%2B1%2F2+ln%28%28e%2B1%29%2F%28e-1%29%29%5E7%2B26%2F%28e%5E2-1.0%29) numerically

Comment: @TymaGaidash Yes, Now although there might be a closed form, now I have no concrete reason to believe so, should I close the question?

Comment: @BlackEmperor Maybe someone else will come up with a series expansion/closed form of the integral. It could be left open

Answer (score 7):

*Too long for comments.*

Except if I faced numerical issues (but it does not seem), if there is a limit, it is larger than $\frac e \pi$.

$$I_n=-\frac e \pi+\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{e}\frac{dx}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x\log^n (x)\right)}$$ Computing
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & I_n \\
 500 & -3.35330\times 10^{-4} \\
 600 & -1.94152\times 10^{-4} \\
 700 & -9.32481\times 10^{-5} \\
 800 & -1.75298\times 10^{-5} \\
 900 & +4.13869\times 10^{-5} \\
 1000 & +8.85359\times 10^{-5} \\
 1100 & +1.27123\times 10^{-4} \\
 1200 & +1.59285\times 10^{-4} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$I_n$ starts to be positive when $n \geq 828$.

Now, computing for high accuracy
$$J_n=\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{e}\frac{dx}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x\log^n (x)\right)}$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & J_{10^p} \\
 1 & 0.8176519908449461348723971 \\
 2 & 0.8605477659194535470317740 \\
 3 & 0.8652429349384881496707912 \\
 4 & 0.8657167843653582969578668 \\
 5 & 0.8657694832396586242896018 \\
 6 & 0.8657694832396586242896018 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This number is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

**But**, in comments, $\color{red}{\text{@TymaGaidash}}$ gave the beautiful result
$$\color{blue}{\large\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{e^2-1}{2 e}\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you for the numerical analysis, I was indeed suspicious about the $\frac{e}{\pi}$ result. It might just be a mere coincidence, I think.

Comment: The p = 5 value of 0.8657... is in error. I think you just copied the p = 6 value over it.

Comment: @Zima. This one  http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html   plus another one made by a former PhD students.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thank you very much

Comment: @1729taxi. Nice user name ! But, I repeated the calculations and confirmed. Could you tell me what you obtain for $p=5$ ? Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: @Zima. Give WA `express 1234.56789 through pi and  e`

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici p = 5 gives 0.86576421291150860070040704594283729796836100364817

Answer (score 6):

[Using](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437742/multivaluedness-of-lim-limits-n-to-inftyxn?noredirect=1) $\displaystyle\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}y^\alpha=0,-1<y\le 1$ and $-1\le \ln(x)<1\implies -\frac1e\le x<e$:

$$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\frac1{1+x\left(\ln x\right)^{\alpha}}dx=\frac1{1+0x}=1$$

Therefore:

$$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{e}\frac{dx}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x\left(\ln x\right)^{\alpha}\right)}=\int_\frac1e^e \frac{dx}{x^2+1}=\tan^{-1}(e)-\cot^{-1}(e)=2\tan^{-1}(e)-\frac\pi2$$

Comment: Thank you, I did not see that.